# Help with an Integral $\iint_{S} \frac{dx\wedge dy}{z}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Help with an Integral $\iint_{S} \frac{dx\wedge dy}{z}$ where $S$ is $ \frac{x²}{a²}+\frac{y²}{b²}+\frac{z²}{c²}=1$

What does  $dx\wedge dy$ means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the [**differential 2-form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) based on the [**exterior product** or **wedge product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).